# Which file permissions should be set for NGINX hosted files?

Tags: docker, nginx

When running an NGINX server that hosts static content, which file permissions should be set? The main consideration is to have the safest configuration.

I currently have two dockerized NGINX servers behind a reverse-proxy, one of them containing files with 1000:1000 (copied directly from the host machine), the other with root:root (copied from a multi-stage build). The current configuration works, but I would like to know the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Folders need read and execute (to traverse). Static files just need read. I assume your server is not running scripts. Ownership should not be root but a user/group usable by nginx.